# Singularity of Eikonal equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the case $|\nabla T(\mathbf{x})|^2=\frac{1}{v(\mathbf{x})^2}$ with $T(\mathbf{x}_s)=0$ where $v$ is the velocity not depending on the wave propagation direction.

In many papers, they simply say that there is a singularity at 0 with nor proving nor further comment. Yet it is hard for me to see why a singularity appears at 0.

Comment: The singularity at source was once stated in the second chapter of "PINNeik: Eikonal solution using physics-informed neural networks", and also given as a conclusion on the head of the third page of "Global Structure and Regularity of Solutions to the Eikonal Equation".